# How to make `console.log` work from console in Developer Console (F12) in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, console, console.log, developer-tools

I'm trying to do some logging via `console.log` in Chrome's Developer Tools console but no output gets logged.

Here's an example:

```
> console.log('hello')
< undefined
```

As you can see (and you can try) nothing got logged. Does anyone know how to log to console with `console.log`?

**Update:**

I found that website I was debugging had its own `console.log` implementation that didnt log to console, that's why nothing showed up.

Does anyone know how to call RAW/Original `console.log` that browser implements?

Comment: It works for me. Very clean install of Chrome (~4 days old). What plugins are you running on Chrome. http://imgur.com/auPkWjJ

Comment: I'm running no plugins - it's a fresh Chrome install...

Comment: did your google chrome has been updated ?
If the problem still persist, i think you should reinstall back your chrome, because i have tried with other laptop it works perfectly!

Comment: It think I know what is going on - the website I'm debugging has overridden console.log with its own implementation!

Comment: Now my question becomes - how to call RAW (original) console.log...

Comment: cant you just execute `delete console.log()` to restore the native code?

Comment: @AnthonySherratt Yes I can. That working! Please submit answer for bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the custom function to restore the native code, like so...

```
delete console.log()
```

Comment: Thx It work! (You may award your bounty in 2 hours.) in 2 hr